SOAP - Expecting Parameters , but calls still fail afterwards
I imported a WSDL schema into PostMan which generated the following in the Body page.
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"/>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetUserWSToken xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <request/>
    </GetUserWSToken>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

When I attempt to "Send" the SOAP call, I get the following error:
    <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:DeserializationFailed</faultcode>
    <faultstring xml:lang="en-AU">The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:request. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 8 position 15. 'EndElement' 'request' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' is not expected. Expecting element 'Password'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.</faultstring>

Because it set it's expecting the element password, I changed it to reflect the following with fake username/password to see if it got an authentication issue:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"/>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetUserWSToken xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <UserName/>test</UserName>
      <Password/>test</Password>
    </GetUserWSToken>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

It now fails with the below:
    <s:Fault>
        <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:DeserializationFailed</faultcode>
        <faultstring xml:lang="en-AU">The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'GetUserWSToken'. End element 'GetUserWSToken' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' expected. Found text 'test'. Line 8, position 22.</faultstring>

I'm very new to SOAP and wonder if anyone knew what I was doing wrong here?

Remove the forward slash from the UserName/ and Password/ elements.  This is making the XML invalid, and is causing it to error on the GetUserWSToken leaf.  This makes it a self closing tag.  Your initial WSDL has it has request/ as its just a placeholder and I suspect you need to put your username\password within that leaf.  It would be useful to post a link to the documentation for this API to know whether you need to wrap the  and  elements with  or not.

If it helps anyone else, I switched to using SoapUI and that generated the XML to pass, and it worked first time.
The moral of the story, SoapUI made life a lot easier compared to Postman.
What worked was:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetUserWSToken>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:request>
            <Password>xx</Password>
            <UserName>xx</UserName>
         </tem:request>
      </tem:GetUserWSToken>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

